# In Objective-C++, for testing, how can I make a class nil at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

Here's the situation:

In async functions, I capture a weakSelf.

```
__block auto weakSelf = self;
```

Then, inside the block, I capture a strongSelf of that weakSelf.

```
[_someIvar someAsyncMethod:^{
   __strong auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
}];
```

But, if strongSelf is nil, I do some error handling and reporting.

```
if (!strongSelf) {
   _NotifyDelegate(someDeallocationError); // C
}
```

The whole thing:

```
__block auto weakSelf = self;
[_someIvar someAsyncMethod:^{
   __strong auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
   if (!strongSelf) {
      // How can I trigger this line?
      _NotifyDelegate(someDeallocationError); // C
   }
}
}];
```

This is all legacy code, and I'm adding unit tests using OCMock. How can I make strongSelf nil at runtime and trigger that delegate notification?

Comment: If you remove all references to that object, then the object should be deallocated, and the weak reference should become nil.

Comment: use dispatch to delay the asyncMethod or use runtime to exchange the implementation to insert code to set the self to nil?

Comment: @childrenOurFuture I'd be happy to upvote and accept if you posted an example :)

Comment: Is there any C++ here other than the `auto` type inference? It doesn't look like it to me. In that case changing the title from "Objective-C++" to just "Objective-C" will likely get you more eyeballs as Objective-C++ is a very niche thing with relatively few experts (hi!) answering questions.

Comment: I'm confused why you would want to. if weak self is not nil at assignment strong self cannot be nil. If you want to test nil weak self just test nil... Or maybe add some details of what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: if weak self is nil at assignment strong self will likewise be nil..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified any class names as far as I can see, but assuming you have:

```
@interface SomeClass

…

@end

…

@interface IvarClass
- (void) someAsyncMethod:(void(^)(void))block;
@end

…

@implementation SomeClass
{
    IvarClass* _someIvar;
}
…

- (void)someMethod
{
  __block auto weakSelf = self;
  [_someIvar someAsyncMethod:^{
    __strong auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (!strongSelf) {
      // How can I trigger this line?
      _NotifyDelegate(someDeallocationError); // C
    }
  }];
}

@end
```

In that case, I would subclass `IvarClass` with a `StubIvarClassDelayedAsync` where you override `- (void) someAsyncMethod:` so that the block is simply stored in an ivar. You then implement another method on it along the lines of `- (void)completeAsyncMethod` which calls the block.

You will need to use an instance of this `StubIvarClassDelayedAsync` as your `_someIvar` in your test - either you can inject this directly via the existing API on `SomeClass`, otherwise you may may need to subclass `SomeClass` to change wherever the production instance is created.

Putting it all together in the test method: Within an `@autoreleasepool` block, create an instance of your `SomeClass` (or its stub subclass), prepare it with an instance of `StubIvarClassDelayedAsync`, then call `someMethod`. This in turn should cause your overridden version of `someAsyncMethod:` to be called, which stores the block reference. (You can assert that the method was called for good measure.) `nil` out the `SomeClass` pointer in your test and close the pool block to remove any last references. You may want to assert that `dealloc` is called on your `SomeClass instance`, which you can easily do if using a dummy subclass. Make sure to retain a pointer to your `StubIvarClassDelayedAsync` instance however. Finally, call `completeAsyncMethod` on that stub instance, which should cause the block to take the error handling branch.

I'd be more specific about a code example if you provided a little more than just unnamed fragments, if you've got code preceding or following these fragments within the respective methods, then that may need to be taken into account or refactored first. Real names would also be useful.

Comment: Sorry, this is prod stuff for my company, so I can't give any examples that wouldn't have made up names anyway. I know -- it's not ideal.

Any chance you'd be willing to write up an example? The explanation is nice, but code often speaks for itself. Thanks for the writeup!